# How can I find an element inside a frameset?

Tags: python, splinter

How can I find an element inside a frameset using Python splinter?

```
<frameset border="0" rows="100">
<frame id="banner898989898"> # this id will change each new login
.....
<body>
<div id="1">
<div class="2">
<div>
<form id="2">
    <input type = text id = "3"> # I want to find this element and then to fill it
```

I tried `find_by_css`, fi`nd_by_xpath`, `find_by_tag,` `find_by_name`, `find_by_value` and `find_by_id` with WebDriver: `find_element_by_xpath`.

I got an `ElementDoesNotExist` exception, although I succeded in finding other elements with the syntax above.

Comment: I find the solution: ""frame = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame) "". this code snippet will move focus to frame and then I can find_by_id the element.